# Why is this returning an empty list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Not too sure what I am doing wrong here.
I am trying to convert all values in input list to floats.
Then print the newly converted values out.

```
class Data_Manager:
    def __init__(self, input_data):
        self.data = input_data
        self.out_list = []
        self.get_single_data = self.get_single_data(value=self.data)
        
    def get_single_data(self, value):
        try:
            success, value = True, float(value)
        except:
            success, value = False, value
        return success, value
        
    def convert_data(self):
        output_list = [self.get_single_data(value)[1] for value in self.data if self.get_single_data(value)[0]]
        self.out_list.append(output_list)
        return output_list
    
    def display(self):
        return self.out_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_data = ["4.1",22,-12,-1,"25","?",0.55,"w",-3.6,"Z",22.12]
    dm = Data_Manager(input_data)
    print(dm.display())

>>[]
```

Comment: Do you call `convert_data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in line five of your code `self.get_single_data = self.get_single_data(value=self.data)` you are re-assigning `def get_single_data` method to the result of the same method which is a `tuple`. In your `if __name__ == "__main__":` block when you call the code `dm.display()` it only returns the `self.out_list` which is an empty list.

Now you can call `dm.convert_data()` method which will do all the operations and populate `self.out_list` but remember in your `__init__` method, you have re-assigned `get_single_data` method to the output of the same method so when you call `convert_data` you will get `TypeError`.

You can remove this line `self.get_single_data = self.get_single_data(value=self.data)` in the `__init__` method or rename `self.get_single_data` to a different name.

Try this solution:

```py
class Data_Manager:
    def __init__(self, input_data):
        self.data = input_data
        self.out_list = []

    def get_single_data(self, value):
        try:
            success, value = True, float(value)
        except:
            success, value = False, value
        return success, value

    def convert_data(self):
        output_list = [self.get_single_data(value)[1] for value in self.data if self.get_single_data(value)[0]]
        self.out_list.append(output_list)
        return output_list

    def display(self):
        return self.out_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_data = ["4.1", 22, -12, -1, "25", "?", 0.55, "w", -3.6, "Z", 22.12]
    dm = Data_Manager(input_data)
    dm.convert_data()
    print(dm.display())
```

```sh
[[4.1, 22.0, -12.0, -1.0, 25.0, 0.55, -3.6, 22.12]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `display` function only returns `out_list` which you initialise as empty. Nowhere do you call your `convert_data` function.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why python is accepting that code, but i think you failure is this line
`self.get_single_data = self.get_single_data(value=self.data)`
you are using a function like a property.
if you use this line, that can it made working `self.out_list = self.get_single_data(value=self.data)`